# Return Ajax Link in modal pop-up window

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the script code below to get results from my database based on the ID of a button when the user clicks it. The database results return fine in the form alert(msg) I am testing as an output. Could someone please help as to how I might return in the results in a modal window instead? I am using bootstrap for my application which uses [bootstrap-modal.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), I can't figure out how I might integrate the two scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {
       $('.ajax-link').click( function() {
        $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function(msg) {
          alert(msg);
        });
        return false; // don't follow the link!
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Example of a bootstrap modal call:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#userGuide').modal({
    backdrop: true;
  });
});
</script>
```

UPDATE: This is the code on the page I am trying to return the user #userGuide from using $.get based on the ID of the button clicked:

```
    <?php

    //MySQL Database Connect
    require 'config.php';

    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('CALL sp_get_recipe_items(:id)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT,4000);
    $res = $stmt->execute();

    if ($res){
        while( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() ){
            echo "<div id='userGuide' class='modal hide fade'><div class='modal-body'>".$row->Ingredient."&nbsp;".$row->Quantity."&nbsp;".$row->UoM."&nbsp;</div></div>";
            }

    }else{
    $arr = $sth->errorInfo();
    echo "Execution failed with MYSQL: " . $arr[0] . "\n";
    die();
    }                      

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajax-link').click(function(event) {
        $('#container').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
            $('#container').modal({
                backdrop: true
            });
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

This uses the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to load content into the `container` element, so you need to add a new element on the page:

```
<div id="container" style="display:none"></div>
```

then uses the callback to show the dialog (`.modal()`) using the container. As you are returning multiple `<div>`s you need to add them to a container before making that the dialog.

Also added the `event` parameter to the `click` callback function and using [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) instead of `return false`.

Note that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and

```
$(function() {
```

do the same thing - [the second is short hand for the first.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

### Update

If you look at the docs for the modal window you will see the markup needs to be

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div>Butter & nbsp; 45 & nbsp; grams & nbsp;</div>
   <div>Flour & nbsp; 12 & nbsp; grams & nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then you use `$('#myModal').modal(options)` to show the window ....

So i suggest you try this, first edit your PHP loop :

```
echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
while( $row = $stmt->fetchObject() ){
   echo "<div>".$row->Ingredient."&nbsp;".$row->Quantity."&nbsp;".$row->UoM."&nbsp;</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

this will create the body of the window ... then already on your page have this :

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal"></div>
```

and finally your JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajax-link').click(function(event) {
        $('#modal-container').load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
            $('#modal-container').modal({
                backdrop: true
            });
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});​
```

Then your not duplicating any `id`s and loading the content into an already existing container.

Comment: Hi ManseUK thank you for the response. That doesn't seem to work for me. I have updated the question with further details that might help clarify my problem better

Comment: Hi @ManseUK I think it's almost there, the modal darkened modal screen appears but the results are still missing. My response in firebug reads <div id='userGuide' class='modal hide fade'><div class='modal-body'>Flour&nbsp;12&nbsp;grams&nbsp;</div></div><div id='userGuide' class='modal hide fade'><div class='modal-body'>Butter&nbsp;45&nbsp;grams&nbsp;</div></div> after I included the modal hide and body classes the plugin requires. I've updated my code above any further help is much appreciated.

Comment: @php_d Ok one problem is that you have mutliple `id`s that are the same - this is a problem - `id`s should be unique - i will update my answer with a suggestion on how this could work

Comment: thanks again for the update sorry to keep bugging you! The code still doesn't seem to work with the container. It just returns the darkened screen with no body again.

Comment: brilliant thank you so very much for your help (and patience)! That is working perfectly now I just need to clean up the style. Also I understand what I was doing wrong, much appreciated!

Comment: @php_d no probs - i learnt a few things along the way - never used the twitter libraries